# ¿Cómo pasar valores de distintos text box a datagrid view?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, datagridview

Tengo que pasar distintos valores que ya tengo en varios txt a un datagrid view (sin base de datos de por medio en esto) y que se muestren los datos en el dgv.

Por ejemplo: txt.idproducto , txtnombreproducto, txtprecio, txtmoneda.

Mi problema es que encontré varios ejemplos pero no me han servido ya que, o me sustituyen un artículo por otro en la misma fila, o se acumulan una al lado de otra las columnas.

Necesito cargar los datos de un artículo, escribir mas datos y cargarlos en la siguiente fila.

Desde ya agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Podrias mostrarnos que intentaste hasta ahora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi pregunta había sido que, si tengo distintos valores en distintos txtbox, como pasarlos a un datagridview. Encontré que me funcionó así:

```
Sub columnasdeldatagridview1()
    dgvCarrito.Columns.Add("id_producto", "ID")
    dgvCarrito.Columns.Add("nombre", "Nombre")
    dgvCarrito.Columns.Add("precio", "Precio")
    dgvCarrito.Columns.Add("moneda", "Moneda")
End Sub
```

Y luego en el boton agregar

```
 Private Sub btnAgregar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAgregar.Click
datagridview1.Rows.Add(txtIDProducto.Text, txtNombre.Text, txtPrecio.Text, txtMoneda.Text)        
End Sub
```

De esa forma me funcionó al menos a mi. Gracias de todas formas :D
Saludos desde Uruguay!

Comment: Estimado, para cerrar tu respuesta recuerda que debes marcarla, aparece un "check" que se coloca verde, debajo de la votación en la respuesta.

Comment: @harifo Si, muchas gracias, lo quise hacer en el momento pero me saltó un cartel que creo decía esperar 7hs.... Después se me pasó.
Muchas gracias igual por hacerme acuerdo de ello. Disculpa las molestias.